# Check User Status Facebook, Without API

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to check if user loged in or not into facebook without using facebook API, i could easily do it using the API, but for some reason i want to do it without the help of facebook API if and only if it's possible .

Example to clear things up:

- loged in message "ok" or what ever.
- not loged in redirect to facebook.com

no auth or what so ever as simple as that

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to check if the user is logged in or not without including the Facebook API.

You can easily check if logged or not using the Facebook JS SDK